# Keep adding a matrix in an iterative way

Tags: python

I have a code which looks like this. (Please no numpy related help...sorry)

```
X = [[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
    [7 ,8,9]]

empty = [[0,0,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]


result = [[0,0,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]

Final = [[0,0,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]



for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(X)):
            result[i][j] = X[i][j] + empty[i][j]
            Final[i][j]=X[i][j] + result[i][j]


for r in Final: 
    print(r)
```

Basically, i want to add X matrix with an empty matrix at first, then store that matrix in some other matrix of the same dimension and later on keep adding X to it until any number of iterations i want. Ultimately, how can i change the part where the final matrix will give an outcome of a matrix which has the same dimension as X but the elements are gonna be added values of each elements in the X matrix? I hope my question is clear. For any further clarifications please don’t hesitate to knock me. :)

Comment: There is no question.

Comment: What does adding an empty matrix do?

Comment: Ok basically i have a matrix 'X' which i want to add to an empty matrix of the same dimension first. 

After that it will add the result of the previous addition with the matrix 'X' again and continuously for a number of iterations. 

Could you provide a solution without Numpy? Please?

Comment: But an empty matrix is empty, it's the additive identity. It does nothing in addition.

Comment: Ok then how about adding the matrix 'X' for 3 times using a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, you are better off using arrays from the `numpy` package. This will allow you to add matrices together directly, instead of elementwise. For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3],
             [4, 5, 6],
             [7, 8, 9]])

y = np.array([[1,2,3],
             [4, 5, 6],
             [7, 8, 9]])

z = x + y
print(z)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 2  4  6]
 [ 8 10 12]
 [14 16 18]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the rows of the matrices, then zip the elements of the rows and add them together:

```
def add_matrix(a, b):
    return [[aij + bij for (aij, bij) in zip(ai, bi)]
             for (ai, bi) in zip(a, b)]
```

You can use it like:

```
X = [[12, 7, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

result = add_matrix(X, X)

for row in result:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
[24, 14, 6]
[8, 10, 12]
[14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: Ok how about i want to start off by adding the empty matrix and then keep adding the result of this addition with the matrix 'X'. Any help?

Comment: I want to add the matrix 'X' to itself at first, then keep adding it to itself in an iterative manner. Any help?